# SSR with AC valve doesn't turn off

Tags: arduino, solid-state-relay, solenoid-valve

I don't have much experience with solid state relays. I am going to describe my problem.

I have a [SMC AC valve](https://www.smcpneumatics.com/VF3130-4DZ1-01F.html) that I want to control with a [Crydom SSR](https://es.rs-online.com/web/p/reles-de-estado-solido/5352980/) and an Arduino UNO.

When I send the signal to the SSR, it activates the valve but if I turn off the signal the valve is still running. I can only turn off the valve by cutting the AC voltage with a switch or disconnecting the voltage source.

I have measured the relay input when I send the signal and when I turn it off. I have not seen anything strange with the oscilloscope.

Can anyone give me some advice?

Comment: Minimum load current is 60 mA. Your valve is very small and your SSR is very large. Try adding a dummy load in parallel and report back.

Comment: Should not, the datasheet states 0.1mA leakage current in off-state

Comment: @winny  has it right - this type of solid state relay requires a minimum load current or it might stay on.  Once off, your leakage spec is valid.

Comment: @winny Thank you very much, that was the problem. The valve consumes so little power that the relay is unable to work properly. I connected a fan I had around here in parallel and now everything works without any problems. I will have to look for a more sensitive relay.

Comment: Or another SSR!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your very large SSR has a minimum load incompatible with your tiny (load-wise) valve.

[image]

Common problems with that configuration includes not being able to turn off.

Possible solutions include increasing the load to meet the 60 mA by adding a dummy load of getting a smaller SSR with lower minimum load requirement.